# What are the font settings which correspond to "default" font styles in iOS 9?

Tags: typography, ios, apple

There is a set of [default font styles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFontDescriptor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Text_Styles) accessible via the iOS API. What settings (font size, weight, etc.) do they correspond to by default on an iPhone 6 running iOS 9? Does this vary across phones/tablets? (I only know that it varies if accessibility settings are modified.)

The existence of these defaults is described in [the wwdc talk  introducing the SF font family](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-804/) at ~ 18:42.